# How to use Google API without users having to allow third party cookies on the browser?

Tags: google-sheets, cookies, browser, google-api, third-party-cookies

Recent versions of Chrome and other browsers are blocking third party cookies by default and users can allow those cookies by, for example, clicking on an eye icon in Chrome and selecting to allow third party cookies.

I have a web application that uses Google Sheet API and Google drive file picker and it needs third party cookies to work, is there a way to set my application so that users don't have to manually allow third party cookies?

Comment: Are you getting errors from that or is that you want those cookies to be automatically forced into the user's browser?

Comment: If the third party cookies aren't enable there's an error message to the user, but I would like the user to don't have to enable third party cookies.

Comment: This is what I could find on the Google API third party cookies: [Third-party cookies and data blocked](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/troubleshooting#third-party_cookies_and_data_blocked) It provides two workaround for this issue